# How to run terminal command in Android application?

Tags: java, android, terminal

How to send a command to the terminal through android app and get the output back? For example, sending "ls /" and getting the output to print it in the GUI?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [Runtime.exec](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runtime#exec(java.lang.String%5B%5D)) to get a process, [waitFor](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Process#waitFor()) it to finish, and then read its output out of its output and error streams.

Comment: I'm getting "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.os.Exec"

Answer (score 1):

Different solutions could be found here: http://code.google.com/p/market-enabler/wiki/ShellCommands
I've not tested them yet.

Answer (score 1):

Try this answer there is way to run shell commands on android programmatically
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3350332/2425851