# Android: Get Hardware Information Programmatically

Tags: android, android-hardware

I have a requirement for obtaining the hardware related information on an Android device that runs my application. I need information of the following sort.

- CPU Manufacturer, model and serial number
- SD Card Manufacturer and serial number
- Camera Manufacturer and other related specs
- Bluetooth related hardware information
- WiFi related hardware information
- RAM Vendor / model
- Display vendor and model

Any help on this topic would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try `getResources().getConfiguration()`;

Comment: @heshan Perera- did you find these hardware informations, if so please update your answer so that others like me can get help from this. Thanks.,

Comment: @Khanna No, I did not manage to find this information.

Answer (score 48):

```
    Log.i("TAG", "SERIAL: " + Build.SERIAL);
    Log.i("TAG","MODEL: " + Build.MODEL);
    Log.i("TAG","ID: " + Build.ID);
    Log.i("TAG","Manufacture: " + Build.MANUFACTURER);
    Log.i("TAG","brand: " + Build.BRAND);
    Log.i("TAG","type: " + Build.TYPE);
    Log.i("TAG","user: " + Build.USER);
    Log.i("TAG","BASE: " + Build.VERSION_CODES.BASE);
    Log.i("TAG","INCREMENTAL " + Build.VERSION.INCREMENTAL);
    Log.i("TAG","SDK  " + Build.VERSION.SDK);
    Log.i("TAG","BOARD: " + Build.BOARD);
    Log.i("TAG","BRAND " + Build.BRAND);
    Log.i("TAG","HOST " + Build.HOST);
    Log.i("TAG","FINGERPRINT: "+Build.FINGERPRINT);
    Log.i("TAG","Version Code: " + Build.VERSION.RELEASE);
```

Answer (score 39):

```
Log.i("ManuFacturer :", Build.MANUFACTURER);
Log.i("Board : ", Build.BOARD);
Log.i("Display : ", Build.DISPLAY);
```

More info can be found at from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html

Comment: Yes I saw this, but it does not meet my requirement. It does not provide me with any information such as the CPU vendor, clock speed etc. Is there a way to access that info through this class ?

Comment: I would also like to know the device camera specs

Answer (score 13):

**This Code give you information about following **

1. Manufacturer of device
2. Brand
3. Model
4. Board
5. Hardware
6. Serial No.
7. Android_ID
8. Screen Resolution
9. Screen Density
10. Boot Loader
11. User
12. Host
13. API Level
14. Build ID
15. Build Time
16. Fingerprint

    ```
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        double x = Math.pow(mWidthPixels / dm.xdpi, 2);
        double y = Math.pow(mHeightPixels / dm.ydpi, 2);
        screenInches = Math.sqrt(x + y);
        rounded = df2.format(screenInches);
        densityDpi = (int) (dm.density * 160f);




    Manufacturer_value = Build.MANUFACTURER;
    Brand_value = Build.BRAND;
    Model_value = Build.MODEL;
    Board_value = Build.BOARD;
    Hardware_value = Build.HARDWARE;
    Serial_nO_value = Build.SERIAL;
    UID_value = tManager.getDeviceId();
    android_id = 
    Settings.Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(), 
    Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    ScreenResolution_value = mHeightPixels + " * " + mWidthPixels + " Pixels";
    screen_size = rounded + " Inches";
    screen_density = String.valueOf(densityDpi) + " dpi";
    BootLoader_value = Build.BOOTLOADER;
    User_value = Build.USER;
    Host_value = Build.HOST;
    Version = Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
    API_level = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT + "";
    Build_ID = Build.ID;
    Build_Time = Build.TIME + "";
    Fingerprint = Build.FINGERPRINT;
    ```

Comment: What is 11. User & 12. Host is all about?

Comment: Hy, @HardikVinzava here is link where you can find all details 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build

Answer (score 8):

You can also get real-time hardware info. Build.* parameters are set during compilation of Android before even deploying it on hardware itself.

You can access Linux real-time hardware info by reading /proc/* "files".

You can do that with
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3528239/997381

Simply as command put `cat /proc/cpuinfo`.

You can test this with `adb shell`, and you don't need root permissions.

Answer (score 7):

maybe someone needs kotlin solution

[image: example]

```kotlin
class DeviceInfoHelper constructor(val context: Context) {

    val model = deviceModel

    val imei = context.imei

    val hardware: String? = HARDWARE

    val board: String? = BOARD

    val bootloader: String? = BOOTLOADER

    val user: String? = USER

    val host: String? = HOST

    val version: String? = RELEASE

    val apiLevel = SDK_INT

    val id: String? = ID

    val time = TIME

    val fingerPrint: String? = FINGERPRINT

    val display: String? = DISPLAY

    private val deviceModel
        @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
        get() = capitalize(
                if (MODEL.toLowerCase().startsWith(MANUFACTURER.toLowerCase())) {
                    MODEL
                } else {
                    "$MANUFACTURER $MODEL"
                })


    private fun capitalize(str: String) = str.apply {
        if (isNotEmpty()) {
            first().run { if (isLowerCase()) toUpperCase() }
        }
    }

    private val Context.imei
        @SuppressLint("HardwareIds", "MissingPermission")
        get() = telephonyManager?.run {
            if (isReadPhoneStatePermissionGranted()) {
                if (SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    imei
                } else {
                    deviceId
                }
            } else DEFAULT_DEVICE_ID
        } ?: DEFAULT_DEVICE_ID

    private fun Context.isReadPhoneStatePermissionGranted() =
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
            ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

    private val Context.telephonyManager
        get() = getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The "Build" class in android.os looks like it will contain some of the information you require

use it as

```
string build = Build.VERSION.DEVICE;
```

[android Hardware Info](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html)

Comment: you cannot assign `Build.VERSION` to a String. It gives compilation error. Instead you can have `Build.VERSION.`_SOMETHING_ (As example **RELEASE** ) and assign it to String. Else you can assign `Build.`_SOMETHING_ (As example **DISPLAY** ) to a String variable. [Android Build](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html) and [Android Build.VERSION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html)Isn't it?

Comment: [`Build.VERSION`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html) does not have a `DEVICE` field, [`Build`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html) itself does. Though, the `String` provided by `Build.DEVICE` only contains the name of the device itself, not any of the information the question asks about.