# How to detect a mobile device manufacturer and model programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, device

I want to find device specification of a mobile phone  for examples, the device manufacturer, model no ( and may be types of sensors in the device, wifi chipset etc..). I want to get the device manufacture/model number (eg. Samsung GT-I9100 i.e Galaxy S2) programmatically. The manufacture/model number is also used in Google Play when installing an app. I want to use this information to make some configuration changes in my hardware dependent app (for eg. power measurement).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Get Hardware Information Programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496872/android-get-hardware-information-programmatically)

Answer (score 170, accepted):

You can get as below:

```
String deviceName = android.os.Build.MODEL;
String deviceMan = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;
```

For more other device details, Please refer this document: **[android.os.Build](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/os/Build.html)**

Comment: Can you imagine, your 7 years old answer is still useful for people like me. :) :) 
Thank you..

Comment: Or use `Build.BRAND` for the brand name.

Comment: The answer is 10 years old and still useful for people like me. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

I just wanna elaborate on how to use the built in Attribute for the future visitors. You can use this method in identifying a Kindle Device(s)

```
public static boolean isKindle(){
        final String AMAZON = "Amazon";
        final String KINDLE_FIRE = "Kindle Fire";

        return (Build.MANUFACTURER.equals(AMAZON) && Build.MODEL.equals(KINDLE_FIRE) ) || Build.MODEL.startsWith("KF");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
String deviceName = android.os.Build.MODEL;
String deviceMan = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;
```

The original solution will work fine, however it will not detect a custom ROM (non OEM) in call cases.  You may want to also evaluate the `android.os.Build.PRODUCT` string or other strings from the Build class.

```
String build = android.os.Build.PRODUCT;
```