# How does Google recognize a device

Tags: android

I just bought a new tablet, a Samsung Galaxy Tab A 7.0".

I connected my Google account to it and it sent me an email telling me my account was connected to a new device: a Samsung Galaxy Tab E 7.0

I'm wondering how does Google determine a device because that quite a mistake :P

The model number of my tablet is SM-T280 and it's name is Galaxy Tab A (2016) according to my device.

After looking on the web, I learned that the model number will also be SM-T280 with a SM-T285 variant.

My question, how does Google recognize a tablet and why in the world would they allow to devices to bear the same model number? I'm just curious about it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Programatically we can find the device manufacturer and model number from which our app is running.Please check this link [How to detect a mobile device manufacturer and model programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489518/how-to-detect-a-mobile-device-manufacturer-and-model-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: Yeah, I know about this, I was wondering more on the Google side. I could they detect that I'm using a device that hasn't even hit the market yet? And how could they assign two similar model numbers to different devices