# Is there any way to detect if the device is running Android One?

Tags: android

I would like to know if there is any way to detect if an Android Device is running [Android One](https://www.android.com/one/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try looking at this : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION, specifically looking at `BASE_OS`

you could do something like this : `Build.VERSION.BASE_OS` to get the name of the `BASE_OS`, however
it seems like that call is only available for api 23 and up.

[image]

**EDIT**
On a custom OS this seems to return null or empty, really not sure if there's any way to do this actually. Don't shoot the messenger here, I was just trying what's in the docs :P

**EDIT 2**
after doing a bit of searching, you can do this :

`String deviceName = android.os.Build.MODEL;`

`String deviceMan = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;`

for my own device, `android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER` this will return : `Xiaomi` as manufacturer, along with the device type for model as : `Redmi Note 7`

: taken from here [How to detect a mobile device manufacturer and model programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489518/how-to-detect-a-mobile-device-manufacturer-and-model-programmatically-in-android)

**Edit 3** closest solution I found was using `android.os.Build` fields, you will probably have to get the names of certain devices(you can use android.os.Build.DEVICE) and do logic specific to those names, can't really see a different solution for this currently... 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build

very cool question though :)

Comment: Build.VERSION.BASE_OS won't work everytime, might return empty

Comment: why would it return empty @ManojPerumarath ?

Comment: Might be because it's **Android** @a_local_nobody

Comment: Is `Build.VERSION.BASE_OS` 100% trustable for this matter? The call being available only for apis 23 or greater doesn't seem to be a problem, as it matches the first release version of the Android One.

Comment: if there's no other solution from someone else specifically with a problem related to my solution, i don't think there's any way of doing it which would be more reliable. simply stating what the documentation says, check it on a device to see if it works

Comment: This doesn't result to identify it's a pure OS/Android One

Comment: yeah, i actually dont know if my solution will work. mine finds the Base_OS, but i dont think it will work for a custom OS

Comment: Does anybody know what a device running Android One would return through that constant (`Build.VERSION.BASE_OS`)? Unfortunately I do not have one at hand right now :/

Comment: @AugustoCarmo i have a xiaomi and it returns null when i run that

Comment: @AugustoCarmo One logic is that, there are only a certain number of Pure OS devices, once you run the app you can check the manufacturer and model to find the device

Comment: @ManojPerumarath, thanks for the contribution :). I'm willing to find a way to do this without depending on a list of all Android One devices available in the market. Up until now, checking `Build.VERSION.BASE_OS` seems to be the most promising answer, but I still have to check if it's 100% reliable.

Comment: @AugustoCarmo Can you please share the code? What is exactly the condition to check if it's Android One or not?

Comment: what Build.VERSION.BASE_OS returns on Android One?