# how can we get the Hardware information of android device programmatically?

Tags: android, android-hardware

As I have refer the old post  i.e. [Android: Get Hardware Information Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496872/android-get-hardware-information-programmatically) but didn't find any relavant answer and also tried to find the solution in google but all in vain. Please help me go forward

[image]

Comment: Offcourse I am aware of that, but there is no relavant answer for that post. Even I have already mentioned there.. You must check it out - @Bxtr

Comment: If someone finds the answer, it should be added to the old question – no need to ask a duplicate.

Comment: @petr Viktorin - thanks for your kind suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

I recently setup such a thing... Upon registration, the phone sends to the webservice (with Retrofit) all the useful harware / software parameters I could find...
Here is the relevant part of the code I used :

```
boolean isRooted = findBinary("su");
PackageInfo pInfo;
String version = "unknown";
try {
    pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
    version = pInfo.versionName;
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

myService.sendPhoneDetails(
    android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT,
    android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE,
    android.os.Build.BRAND,
    android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER,
    android.os.Build.MODEL,
    android.os.Build.SERIAL,
    isRooted,
    version,
    new Callback<Model>() {
        @Override
            public void success(Model model, Response response) {
                // ....
            }
        @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                // ....
            }
        }
    );

private static boolean findBinary(String binaryName) {
    boolean found = false;
    if (!found) {
        String[] places = { "/sbin/", "/system/bin/", "/system/xbin/",
                "/data/local/xbin/", "/data/local/bin/",
                "/system/sd/xbin/", "/system/bin/failsafe/", "/data/local/" };
        for (String where : places) {
            if (new File(where + binaryName).exists()) {
                found = true;

                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

Note that all the phones do not give access to the same info, like the phone number rarely accessible, but those ones look pretty common.

Hope this can help...

Answer (score 2):

Using [Build](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html) class you can get all of this information.

to write down those info in a Toast (For Example) you can use:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+Build.HARDWARE+Build.DEVICE+Build.MANUFACTURER+ "etc..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

for more info about the build class check out the link above.

hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

You can read `/proc/meminfo` and `/proc/cpuinfo` for example. 
These do not require root access and contain information about the memory / cpu.

Details on how to read these can be found here: [Any way to run shell commands on android programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350283/any-way-to-run-shell-commands-on-android-programmatically/3528239#3528239)