# Android: Get mobile hardware information

Tags: java, android, device, android-hardware

I am working on app which tells the user about Device. I go through many questions on SO but didn't find the answer. I want to find

- Model Number
- Android Version
- Base band Version
- Kernel Version
- Build    number
- RAM
  of my Mobile.

  I would really appreciate any kind of help regarding this Thankx.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Get Hardware Information Programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496872/android-get-hardware-information-programmatically)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was using this on my code, so I put all:

```
Log.i("TAG", "SERIAL: " + Build.SERIAL);
Log.i("TAG","MODEL: " + Build.MODEL);
Log.i("TAG","ID: " + Build.ID);
Log.i("TAG","Manufacture: " + Build.MANUFACTURER);
Log.i("TAG","brand: " + Build.BRAND);
Log.i("TAG","type: " + Build.TYPE);
Log.i("TAG","user: " + Build.USER);
Log.i("TAG","BASE: " + Build.VERSION_CODES.BASE);
Log.i("TAG","INCREMENTAL " + Build.VERSION.INCREMENTAL);
Log.i("TAG","SDK  " + Build.VERSION.SDK);
Log.i("TAG","BOARD: " + Build.BOARD);
Log.i("TAG","BRAND " + Build.BRAND);
Log.i("TAG","HOST " + Build.HOST);
Log.i("TAG","FINGERPRINT: "+Build.FINGERPRINT);
Log.i("TAG","Version Code: " + Build.VERSION.RELEASE);
```

Comment: I used it only to know my status of device, to know more go to official doc of google "https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html." ~ Arigato

Comment: @AviParshan, As per the question i answered it. To get more info ask question. Don't downvote. Else also I'm adding some more context to it.

Comment: @W4R10CK Sorry. I thought one should downvote if the answer isn't fitting. It's locked in now. When you edit it, I can reverse the downvote.

Comment: @AviParshan, See the question first, it says **any kind of help regarding this**, that does not means if i dont give RAM details, the answer is wrong. Edit is not suggested to attempt reply. So ask the answer provider with any edit if needed.