# Mobile Info App Android

Tags: android, mobile, hardware

I want to **develop** android app that's tells the info of **mobiles**. My app contains information of

- Model
- Manufacture
- Device
- Product
- Brand
- Android Version
- API level
- Build ID
- Finger Print
- List item

[image: Appp look like this]

App look like this

I don't know how to start this app. I want the idea to start this app.I would really appreciate any kind of help regarding this Thankx.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Get mobile hardware information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39530765/android-get-mobile-hardware-information)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using this on my code, so I put all: (Note: Use String to parse all value and avoid Log as per your usage).

```
Log.i("TAG", "SERIAL: " + Build.SERIAL);
Log.i("TAG","MODEL: " + Build.MODEL);
Log.i("TAG","ID: " + Build.ID);
Log.i("TAG","Manufacture: " + Build.MANUFACTURER);
Log.i("TAG","brand: " + Build.BRAND);
Log.i("TAG","type: " + Build.TYPE);
Log.i("TAG","user: " + Build.USER);
Log.i("TAG","BASE: " + Build.VERSION_CODES.BASE);
Log.i("TAG","INCREMENTAL " + Build.VERSION.INCREMENTAL);
Log.i("TAG","SDK  " + Build.VERSION.SDK);
Log.i("TAG","BOARD: " + Build.BOARD);
Log.i("TAG","BRAND " + Build.BRAND);
Log.i("TAG","HOST " + Build.HOST);
Log.i("TAG","FINGERPRINT: "+Build.FINGERPRINT);
Log.i("TAG","Version Code: " + Build.VERSION.RELEASE);
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help you

```
String s="Debug-infos:";
        s += "\n OS Version: " + System.getProperty("os.version") + "(" + android.os.Build.VERSION.INCREMENTAL + ")";
        s += "\n OS API Level: "+android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE + "("+android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT+")";
        s += "\n Device: " + android.os.Build.DEVICE;
        s += "\n Model (and Product): " + android.os.Build.MODEL + " ("+ android.os.Build.PRODUCT + ")";
```

Comment: thanks for reply i want to get display processor also

Comment: if this answer help you upto some extent, please accept it as answer and up vote. Thanks