# Android h3: A Hexagonal Hierarchical Geospatial Indexing System

Tags: android, uber-api, h3

I want to integrate h3 java binding library to my android app and I'm getting following exception:

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No native resource found at /android-armv7l/libh3-java.so
at com.uber.h3core.H3CoreLoader.copyResource(H3CoreLoader.java:67)

Does anyone used this library before for Android OS?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Initially, following the intended [usage](https://github.com/uber/h3-java#usage) as seen in their README *should* make it work. If it doesn't, see below.

Known Issue: [Android, can't use library](https://github.com/uber/h3-java/issues/23)

`UnsatisfiedLinkError`: This can be encountered when the corresponding native library is not copied/detected in the project. Following [NickRadu's workaround](https://github.com/uber/h3-java/issues/23#issuecomment-417966410) should make it work.
Below is a step-by-step guide.

1. Add a JNI folder in your project app folder and rename it `jniLibs` (`app/src/main/jniLibs`) (for some reason, having it named `jni` only doesn't work for me).
2. [Get the H3 JAR](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/uber/h3/) (make sure you use the same version) and extract the JAR contents.
3. Copy the folders prefixed with `android-` and insert them in the `jniLibs` folder (from step 1).
4. Rename the copied folders, remove the `android-` prefix.
5. Add `splits { abi { enable false } }` to your app's build.gradle file (within `android`).

Done. In general, the library should now work as expected.

If during the app installation you encounter:

- [`INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24572052/4625829), 
  then depending on your *test* device, create a copy of the folder (along with its contents) and rename it as needed. 
  For example, a device running on arm64-v8a, I just made a copy of the `arm64` folder and renamed it to `arm64-v8a`. Or if you're using an emulator, make sure that you're not using one with an `x86` CPU.
- `D8 errors: Invoke-customs are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)`, add these compile options in your app's build.gradle (within `android` -- note that it may change depending on your system's Java version)

  ```
  compileOptions {
      sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
      targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
  ```

*Note: It is best to test the app on multiple CPU architecture types first to see it's behavior.*

To quickly see the CPU Architecture of the device, you could install [Droid Hardware Info](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.inkwired.droidinfo), or run a quick [test code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41605726/4625829) yourself.

Here's a test block I used and its corresponding result logs:

```
private fun testH3() {
    val h3 = H3Core.newSystemInstance()

    val lat = 37.775938728915946
    val lng = -122.41795063018799
    val resolution = 8

    val hexAddr = h3.geoToH3Address(lat, lng, resolution)
    val hex = h3.stringToH3(hexAddr)
    val kRingsResult = h3.kRings(hexAddr, 1)

    Log.d("H3Test", "geoToH3Address: $hexAddr")
    Log.d("H3Test", "stringToH3: $hex")
    Log.d("H3Test", "kRings: $kRingsResult")
}
```

Result:

```
D/H3Test: geoToH3Address: 8828308281fffff
D/H3Test: stringToH3: 613196570331971583
D/H3Test: kRings: [[8828308281fffff], [8828308281fffff, 882830828dfffff, 8828308285fffff, 8828308287fffff, 8828308283fffff, 882830828bfffff, 8828308289fffff]]
```

I made a sample project where the library works as expected. See [`android-uber-h3-sample`](https://github.com/yelsane/android-uber-h3-sample).

Answer (score 1):

Also be advised that the library will not work on Android api < 26 without some modifications to the code. The function that H3Core relies on to parse the hex long to hex string Long.parseUnsignedInt was not added to Android Java until api 26.

Comment: Hi Mendicats. Thanks for this info. Could you point which specific class this is? So we could try to make a workaround. Cheers.

Comment: Tested running a base app with the H3 java lib on devices running Nougat (API 25) and Marshmallow (API 23). The functions work as expected. We have the project target the Java 8 compatibility -- which might be the reason it's working?

Comment: Thanks for that advice, I didn't know you could do that. I'll try that and report back.

Comment: I do have the target compability set to java 1.8. Does calling H3Core.stringToH3 and H3Core.krings work as expected on your end? Those functions are where I'm getting errors.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I'll check that out tomorrow as I'm not on my machine atm. Will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Hi Mendicats. Both work fine on my end. I added a sample testing block and its result in my answer. Cheers.

Comment: Hi Mendicats. It's been a while. Were you able to try it out?

Comment: Hey! Sorry for going AWOL. It still hasn't worked on my end :(

Comment: Hi. Okay. When I get some time, I'll try to come create a base test project and upload it so you can try. However, we've just finished integrating it on our end and it works fine. Even on Android API < 26. Cheers!

Comment: Hey thanks I would appreciate that a lot. I'll keep looking into it in the meanwhile.

Comment: Hey @mendicats. Just managed to create the project (view it [here](https://github.com/yelsane/android-uber-h3-sample)) -- let me know if you can run it or not. So far on the devices that I tested, it works as expected. Cheers!