# How to programmatically fetch the hardware details of GPS module, WiFi Module, Vibrator etc from a android device

Tags: android, wifi, fingerprint, android-hardware

I want to see the Hardware related details of GPS module, WiFi Module, Vibrator, Fingerprint scanner etc from a Android device. These all are hardware part that present inside a Mobile device.

- Manufacturer
- Serial number of hardware.
- Range
- Usage of particular hardware part
- Power Consumption of hardware

How i can programmatically fetch these details in Android?

Is it really possible to fetch this details?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496872/android-get-hardware-information-programmatically

Comment: Those answers not give any details about the hardware part what i mention above.