# How can I read HDMI version on Android?

Tags: android, hdmi

How can I read display related stuff like HDMI version?

Currently, I do not want to change them. I only want to read them in the first place.

Comment: Refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496872/android-get-hardware-information-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Log.i("ManuFacturer :", Build.MANUFACTURER);
Log.i("Board : ", Build.BOARD);
Log.i("Display : ", Build.DISPLAY);
```

You need to use this in Android Studio which would involve building and compiling a simple app. I believe you can keep your device plugged into your main PC and use it as a test device. You will then be able to see the output.