# Is it possible to run a C program on Android

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

I have a program written in C with a standard `main()` function.

Is it possible to run this program on Android, e.g. launching it from my application or from one of the many shell applications? If so, what steps do I need to take to achieve this? Can I just compile the application with the NDK?

I know there are some answered questions on how to link C functions to Android code, mainly pointing out to NDK tutorials, but none of them was, at least for me, clear. It seems that NDK is all about using C functions, not running a fully C compiled program. Is this correct?

Answer (score 5):

All you need to do is compile it for the correct architecture (usually ARM) using a cross compiler (how you get it depends on your linux distribution). Then you can execute it from your (Java-based) like any other excecutable:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandLine);
```

See [Any way to run shell commands on android programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350283/any-way-to-run-shell-commands-on-android-programmatically) for more information about the "executing" part.

Comment: gonna try it out, and come back with insights. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

NDK includes all tools necessary to build an executable from C sources, available for download for Linux, Mac, and Windows. The magic enchantment you should use is **include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)**

Comment: Digged the net to find out how can I compile a simple c file using the ndk-toolchain. So far i got to the point where i need to execute the command arm-linux-androideabi-gcc under the linux shell for compiling my code. So far i was not succesfull using it, since i get compilation error: "defs.h: No such file or directory"

Comment: Only take into account that the article is pretty ancient. New releases of NDK allow and even encourage the following build technique: go to your project's directory and run **ndk-build**. The resulting executable or shared library will be placed to **./libs** directory.

Comment: thank you very much Alex. Can you (or anyone else) explain more about how to use the "ndk-build" command? my intention is simply to compile a c program to be used in an android app, with Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandLine);

Comment: This http://www.packtpub.com/article/creating-compiling-deploying-native-projects-android-ndk is probably the best introduction I saw.

Comment: If you have specific problems, just ask less general questions.

Comment: Here's the way to do it:

Comment: A working example can be found in NDK samples in $NDK_ROOT/samples/test-libstdc++ (or see a mirror: http://mirror.yongbok.net/pub/pub/linux/android/repository/development/ndk/samples/test-libstdc%2b%2b)