# Get Android WiFi "net.hostname" from code

Tags: android, android-wifi

When an Android device connects to a wifi AP, it identifies itself with a name like:

android_cc1dec12345e6054

How can that string be obtained from within an Android app?  Not for the purpose of changing it, just for readout.

EDIT:
This is a screenshot of my router's web interface, showing a list of all connected devices.  Note the two Android devices on the list -- How can that string be read from Java code running on the device?

[image: Router's connection list]

Comment: Not trying to get the router's SSID -- Trying to get the android device's hostname string, which it somehow provides to the router.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Building off of @Merlevede's answer, here's a quick and dirty way to get the property. It's a private API, so it's subject to change, but this code hasn't been modified since at least Android 1.5 so it's probably safe to use.

```
import android.os.Build;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

/**
 * Retrieves the net.hostname system property
 * @param defValue the value to be returned if the hostname could
 * not be resolved
 */
public static String getHostName(String defValue) {
    try {
        Method getString = Build.class.getDeclaredMethod("getString", String.class);
        getString.setAccessible(true);
        return getString.invoke(null, "net.hostname").toString();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return defValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: You weren't kidding about that "Private API"...
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: access to method denied

Comment: Interesting. What OS version and device are you running? This works just fine for me.

Comment: Nexus 7, 2013 model, running 4.4.2.  I'll try an earlier emulator

Comment: Strange. I'm on a Nexus 5 running 4.4.2, so it shouldn't be any different. Can you try with the edited change? (`setAccessible(true)`)

Comment: Just for other Android newbie's - the class `Method` is `java.lang.reflect.Method` and the class `Build` is `android.os.Build`.

Comment: Thanks @JesseChisholm, edited in the imports to make that clearer.

Comment: This will not work in Android O - `Querying the net.hostname system property produces a null result.` - Ref: https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html

Comment: On Galaxy Tab A8 it returns "unknown"

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if this helps but here I go.

From a unix shell (you can download any Terminal app in Google Play), you can get the hostname by typing

```
getprop net.hostname
```

Of course this is not what you want... but... on the other hand, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350283/any-way-to-run-shell-commands-on-android-programmatically) is information on how to execute a unix command from java. Maybe by combining these two you get what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks Merlevede, that helped.  Further investigation shows that "net.hostname" is a deep Java SystemProperty, not exposed in the Android SDK.  It can be made available through reflection, though:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641111/where-is-android-os-systemproperties

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72170364/433718) for the code

Answer (score 6):

Use the [NetworkInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/NetworkInterface.html) object to enumerate the interfaces and get the canonical host name from the interfaces' `InetAddress`. Since you want the wifi name, as a shortcut you can query for `wlan0` directly and if that fails you can enumerate them all like this:

```
import android.test.InstrumentationTestCase;
import android.util.Log;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class NetworkInterfaceTest extends InstrumentationTestCase {
    private static final String TAG = NetworkInterfaceTest.class.getSimpleName();
    public void testNetworkName() throws Exception {
        Enumeration<NetworkInterface> it_ni = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
        while (it_ni.hasMoreElements()) {
            NetworkInterface ni = it_ni.nextElement();
            Enumeration<InetAddress> it_ia = ni.getInetAddresses();
            if (it_ia.hasMoreElements()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "++ NI:   " + ni.getDisplayName());
                while (it_ia.hasMoreElements()) {
                    InetAddress ia = it_ia.nextElement();
                    Log.i(TAG, "-- IA:   " + ia.getCanonicalHostName());
                    Log.i(TAG, "-- host: " + ia.getHostAddress());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That will give you an output like this:

```
TestRunner﹕ started: testNetworkName
++ NI:   lo
-- IA:   ::1%1
-- host: ::1%1
-- IA:   localhost
-- host: 127.0.0.1
++ NI:   p2p0
-- IA:   fe80::1234:1234:1234:1234%p2p0
-- host: fe80::1234:1234:1234:1234%p2p0
++ NI:   wlan0
-- IA:   fe80::1234:1234:1234:1234%wlan0
-- host: fe80::1234:1234:1234:1234%wlan0
-- IA:   android-1234567812345678   <--- right here
-- host: 192.168.1.234
```

Tip: if `InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName().equals(InetAddress.getHostAddress())` you can ignore it as it's not a "real" name.

Comment: Sometimes the domain is included so it is not the plain hostname.

Comment: Will print my IP address and not android-1234567812345678 :( (Samsung Galaxy S3)

Answer (score 0):

For `java`:

you can get the property by below:

```
String str = SystemProperties.get("net.hostname");
```

Answer (score 0):

I used jiangze ren's answer and modified it.

Now you can get hostname by getting IP address of device:

```
   WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
                        final String ip = Formatter.formatIpAddress(wm.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress());
                        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
                        System.out.println(address.getHostName());  // <-- host name is here and not localhost!
```

Comment: Will print my IP address and not android-1234567812345678 :( (Samsung Galaxy S3)

Answer (score 0):

Credits to Merlevede. This is the actually working code based on his answer.

```
    String hostname;
    Process ifc = null;
    try {
        ifc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("getprop net.hostname");
        BufferedReader bis = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ifc.getInputStream()));
        hostname = bis.readLine(); // android-1234567812345678
        ifc.destroy();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

None of the other answers helped me.

Answer (score -2):

you can use the code below:

```
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();  
System.out.println(address.getHostName());  // <-- host name is here!
```

And actually, you can more info using this function. 
such as... 
other devices hostname which are in the same network.

Comment: all this is going to return is `localhost` too.