# Android find CPU Usage of app programmatically from another package

Tags: java, android, cpu

I have an Android app with 3 activities in 1 package. I also have 1 more package(monitoring package) which has java files mainly for monitoring the performance of these 3 activities.Now I need to monitor cpu usage of my app and I need to have this cpumonitor file defined for the same in monitoring package. I am not supposed to touch the 3 activities. How do I achieve this?

I have seen various posts wherein you get the current running process from activitymanager and find cpu usage. In my case, I cant get context from these 3 activities since I am not allowed to edit them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one of those Activities will be working at any one time. So attempting to monitor all 3 is going to be fruitless.

You can however monitor a process by package name.

Run this command through Java:

```
ps -o com.package.name
```

Here is an example of running a [shell command on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3350332/503508).

Comment: What kind of output will I get? I am doing this - Process process = null;
 try {
  process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps -o com.example.buttontestaspect");
 } catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
 BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

Comment: Try accessing your device and typing the command in. `adb shell`. You will need to parse this information yourself.