# How can I write a simple script on android

Tags: android, bash

Is it possible on an Android terminal tou run a simple script?
I'd like to run the following commands

```
$su
$cd /Downloads
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
    try{
    Process su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(su.getOutputStream());

    outputStream.writeBytes("screenrecord --time-limit 10 /sdcard/MyVideo.mp4\n");
    outputStream.flush();

    outputStream.writeBytes("exit\n");
    outputStream.flush();
    su.waitFor();
}catch(IOException e){
    throw new Exception(e);
}catch(InterruptedException e){
    throw new Exception(e);
}
```

read this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350283/any-way-to-run-shell-commands-on-android-programmatically) also.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, search the app store for terminal emulator.