# How to add .sh on apk install and execute them?

Tags: android, file, vi, sh

Well the title say it, but the issue is this:

I have a .sh file with a command `su touch /sdcard/test.txt` to see if it works. But I don't know how to include it when the user install the app. How could I add it? I thought about using something like:

```
su
touch /sdcard/folder/path/test.sh
vi /sdcard/folder/path/test.sh
```

and there create the .sh file, but I don't know how to send the `esc` key to be able to `:wq` I know how to execute the file, and yes my phone is rooted. I just need to know how to include it when the apk is installed and/or how to send the `esc` key to finish the `vi` command.

Thanks

EDIT: I created a `.sh` file called `test.sh` and I created a app which one is for root users. The `test.sh` file only have `touch /sdcard/test.txt` just to see if my java code works. I created a simple app with one button and inside that button click I have this:

```
test.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                try
                {
                    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"su","-c","sh ./path where .sh will be/test.sh"});
                    proc.waitFor();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    String TAG = null;
                    Log.i(TAG, "Doesn't work", ex);
                }
            }
        });
```

BUT I don't know how to or where I have to add my `test.sh` file so when the user install my app the file is there. I tried including

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"su","-c","touch /sdcard/prueba.sh ; vi /sdcard/prubea.sh ; ****Don't know how to edit, use ESC key and :wq****});
                    proc.waitFor();
```

Now when I click my button the app keeps running waiting for me to end the `vi` command, but I don't know how to since I will have to press `esc` to be able to `:wq`... Hope this makes it clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that you have vi installed on the phone, just look up the hex code in ascii for ESC and write that to the input buffer.

Here's a good ASCII chart [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii)

Comment: I still don't get how I could include this, can you please be a little more specific?

Comment: checkout this post. it tells you exactly how to do it. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6953432/1269727

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to perform an action upon installation. This [How to start android service on installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127044/how-to-start-android-service-on-installation) suggests that that's not possible to do.

Comment: Not that way. I want that file to be added so I can execute it. Here's an example, I downloaded a apk called Hot reboot, and in the /data/data/com......quick_reboot/ there's a folder called files and inside it there's a .sh file that the apk run to reboot the phone. How could I do this?

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing. Are you running these commands in "adb shell"? vi and esc has just worked for me without problem. You shouldn't even need the touch command.