# Get file permissions in Android (root)

Tags: android, permissions, root, chmod

After some play around with rooted devices, I got stuck on the files. Let's say we have a file somewhere in the root folder which I want to read/write from my application. The only way I found so far is changing the file permission like

```
String [] cmd = { "su", "-c", "chmod", "777", path};
Process process = new ProcessBuilder(cmd).start();
process.waitFor();
```

This works fine, the problem is that I want to return back the original file permissions after I'm done with it.

Can anybody help me with getting a file/directory current permissions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do `ls -l` on file/directory and parse the output

**EDIT BY OP:** the solution is in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896618/read-command-output-inside-su-process). This answer just pushed me in the right direction.

Comment: I like the idea, just made some tries but it will be tricky unless I don't have access to the directory. I continue tomorrow.

Comment: if called with `su ls -l`, it doesn't return anything.

Comment: su ls -l needs root permissions (Root device)