# how to get apk file to run atinout programm on android mobile?

Tags: android, c, apk

When I asked about [implement at command on rooted android and get the result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23316929/implement-at-command-on-rooted-android-and-get-the-result) the answer I get is a program called atinout:  http://atinout.sourceforge.net/  I downloaded the folder which include c program.

The problem is that I failed in getting the apk file.

the one how write the answer told me "To compile normally you just run make". but this didn't get me the apk file. it got me an executable file.

What shall I do to get apk file?

Comment: can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to port this program to android-java. 
This program is only for Linux-distri's. Maybe you can use the c-code in a android app, but that is a little bit tricky, and you have to compile it for every cpu.

[Edit]
If you try it like this:

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/51131/how-to-use-android-modem-without-using-pc

you run the program on your pc and you use your android as modem.

Comment: Till now I couldn't find the answer. I want to know the way to get apk file for atinout program.

Comment: All I see on there homepage is, that they don't provide an apk/android version. If you want to have one, you must write your own port.