# Dealing with GSM modem by JNI in android

Tags: android, c, galaxy, at-command, modem

I'm developing a program that send at-command to GSM modem and I want to read the response.

Some programmers advice me to use `atinout` program in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23316929/implement-at-command-on-rooted-android-and-get-the-result).

so I ported to android and simplify the code to this C code, because I don't want to use files (input and output):

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_marakana_NativeLib_hello(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj)
{
FILE *modem;
char *line="AT\r";
bool success;
int res;

modem = fopen("/dev/smd0", "r+b");
if (modem == NULL) 
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "2fopen() failed: /dev/smd0\n");

res = fputs(line, modem);
if (res < 0)
return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, ("5failed to send '%s' to modem res = " + res,line));  

line = fgets(buf, (int)sizeof(buf), modem);
if (line == NULL)
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "6EOF from modem\n");
strcpy(buf2, line);
strip_cr(buf2);

res = fclose(modem);
if (res != 0) 
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,  ("9closing modem failed: %s\n", strerror(errno)));

return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, buf2);
}

static void strip_cr(char *s)
{
char *from, *to;
from = to = s;
while (*from != '\0') {
    if (*from == '\r') {
        from++;
        continue;
    }
    *to++ = *from++;
}
*to = '\0';
}
```

The problem is:
The modem response is the same request. That mean I received `AT` from the function.

note: my mobile is Samsung Galaxy Win Duos.

Is the problem in the modem of my mobile. or in my code? how can I get the response of at command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have simplified too much; you **MUST** keep the logic that *reads and parses* everything that the modem sends back. After sending any AT command line you should continue processing responses (and do nothing else!) until you get a Final result code, e.g. `OK`, `ERROR`, `+CME ERROR: ...` etc.

As for the getting echo of the command line this is normal modem behaviour, although you can turn off echo with `ATE0`, see "5.2.3 Command line echo" in [V.250](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-V.250-200307-I/en). That specification is the most fundamental AT command document that anyone working with AT commands benefits from reading. Read all of chapter 5 and then look into specific command if applicable in chapter 6.