# get detailed process information in Android

Tags: android, process, rooted-device, dynamic-analysis

I'm going to write an app to do dynamic analysis of processes. In order to achieve this I want to have detailed statistics about process running on my phone. 
 **Note:** I have rooted phone so some limits are removed.
So here is my question, how can I collect process information in detail dynamically? I know results of `top`,`ps` commands can help me, however I don't know how to call them or do I have access these commands on a rooted phone?

As I searched around the web `ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo` is no longer useful since It provide limited information since Lolipop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux `top` and `ps` are available even if the device is not rooted. You can run them from your app with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`. If you need to run a command "elevated", check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6953432/192373.

Also, if your app has root permissions, it can examine the [`/proc` filesystem](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html), Linux style.

Comment: May i ask you to help me and have a look at my other question related to this over here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31246218/1080355