# Android: Differntiate running Apps from other processes in android

Tags: android, shell, adb, dynamic-analysis

I did run `ps` command in shell on my phone. The question is how can I differentiate processes related to applications which I executed as a normal phone user such as Google Play, Adobe Reader and etc.?

 As I noticed some processes are run by user names in format `app_xxx` and as childs of process `zygote` however there are plenty of them which include background services and system services. Are there any method to make a short-list of them like the list my phone displays when i press app list button (currently it shows only 6 apps with thumbnails in running applications list)?

here is the output of `ps` in adb shell:

```
USER     PID   PPID  VSIZE  RSS     WCHAN    PC         NAME
root      1     0     416    272   ffffffff 00000000 S /init
root      2     0     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S kthreadd
root      3     2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S ksoftirqd/0
root      6     2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S migration/0
root      7     2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S watchdog/0
root      12    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S khelper
root      13    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S pm
root      14    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S suspend
root      15    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S sync_system_wor
root      16    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S sync_supers
root      17    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S bdi-default
root      18    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S kblockd
root      19    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S irq/217-tegra-o
root      20    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S khubd
root      21    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S irq/118-tps6586
root      22    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S kmmcd
root      23    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S kconservative
root      24    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S cpu-tegra
root      25    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S khungtaskd
root      26    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S kswapd0
root      27    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S fsnotify_mark
root      28    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S aio
root      29    2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S crypto
root      180   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S tegradc.0
root      181   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S tegradc.0
root      182   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S nvhdcp1
root      183   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S tegradc.1
root      184   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S tegradc.1
root      185   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S lcd_bl
root      186   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S smdpdpd
root      187   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S tegra-kbc
root      188   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S irq/220-sec_tou
root      189   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S bh1721fvc_wq
root      190   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S ak8975c_wq
root      191   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S kxtf9_wq
root      192   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S kstriped
root      193   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S kondemand
root      194   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S kinteractiveup
root      199   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S usbhid_resumer
root      200   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S binder
root      202   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S wm8994
root      203   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S l2cap
root      204   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S krfcommd
root      205   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S sec_jack_wq
root      206   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S irq/371-sec_hea
root      207   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S mmcqd
root      208   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S p3_TA_workqueue
root      209   1     344    172   ffffffff 00000000 S /sbin/ueventd
root      210   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S jbd2/mmcblk0p4-
root      211   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S ext4-dio-unwrit
root      212   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S jbd2/mmcblk0p5-
root      213   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S ext4-dio-unwrit
root      215   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S jbd2/mmcblk0p8-
root      216   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S ext4-dio-unwrit
root      217   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S jbd2/mmcblk0p1-
root      218   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S ext4-dio-unwrit
system    219   1     864    272   ffffffff 00000000 S /system/bin/servicemanage
r
root      220   1     4564   740   ffffffff 00000000 S /system/bin/vold
root      222   1     5256   900   ffffffff 00000000 S /system/bin/netd
system    224   1     35660  22828 ffffffff 00000000 S /system/bin/surfaceflinge
r
root      225   1     468560 22484 ffffffff 00000000 S zygote
drm       226   1     13236  1392  ffffffff 00000000 S /system/bin/drmserver
media     227   1     47792  6756  ffffffff 00000000 S /system/bin/mediaserver
bluetooth 228   1     1356   312   ffffffff 00000000 S /system/bin/dbus-daemon
root      229   1     916    380   ffffffff 00000000 S /system/bin/installd
keystore  230   1     1804   400   ffffffff 00000000 S /system/bin/keystore
system    231   1     5324   712   ffffffff 00000000 S /system/bin/tvoutserver
gps       232   1     16720  1808  ffffffff 00000000 S /system/bin/gpsd
radio     233   1     10552  1432  ffffffff 00000000 S /system/bin/rild
system    234   1     8452   756   ffffffff 00000000 S /system/bin/drexe
system    235   1     1108   304   ffffffff 00000000 S /system/bin/npsmobex
media_rw  236   1     1652   1088  ffffffff 00000000 S /system/bin/sdcard
shell     237   1     804    388   ffffffff 00000000 S /system/bin/sh
shell     238   1     3456   180   ffffffff 00000000 S /sbin/adbd
shell     254   1     776    244   c00e3e00 aff0c1fc S /system/bin/immvibed
root      255   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S irq/182-3d
root      257   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S smdctld
root      265   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S irq/178-2d_0
root      275   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S flush-179:0
root      277   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S irq/184-disp0
root      286   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S irq/261-accesso
root      287   2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S irq/309-dock_de
system    290   225   589008 63864 ffffffff 00000000 S system_server
system    337   225   512444 41632 ffffffff 00000000 S com.android.systemui
app_92    346   225   500512 27356 ffffffff 00000000 S com.samsung.sec.android.i
nputmethod.axt9
radio     353   225   499624 23640 ffffffff 00000000 S com.android.phone
app_47    356   225   478476 19100 ffffffff 00000000 S com.sec.pcw.device
app_62    358   225   507484 75304 ffffffff 00000000 S com.android.launcher
app_48    387   225   607984 28188 ffffffff 00000000 S com.google.process.gapps
app_15    436   225   493320 26488 ffffffff 00000000 S android.process.acore
app_238   622   1     481576 19872 ffffffff 00000000 S me.onemobile.android
app_85    1342  225   481256 20568 ffffffff 00000000 S com.android.providers.cal
endar
app_75    1627  225   516084 23844 ffffffff 00000000 S com.android.email
root      1740  2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S iscan_sysioc
root      1741  2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S pno_sysioc
root      1742  2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S dhd_watchdog
root      1743  2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S dhd_dpc
root      1744  2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S dhd_sysioc
root      1745  2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S ksdioirqd/mmc1
wifi      1754  1     2624   960   ffffffff 00000000 S /system/bin/wpa_supplican
t
dhcp      3813  1     948    392   ffffffff 00000000 S /system/bin/dhcpcd
app_384   4132  1     748    284   ffffffff 00000000 S sys-log
app_134   4527  225   481000 24828 ffffffff 00000000 S com.noshufou.android.su
app_60    4567  225   505932 28672 ffffffff 00000000 S com.google.android.apps.m
aps
root      5249  2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S kworker/u:0
root      5282  1     732    268   ffffffff 00000000 S /system/bin/debuggerd
app_325   5551  225   492004 31712 ffffffff 00000000 S com.yahoo.mobile.client.a
ndroid.mail:com.yahoo.snp.service
app_15    6132  225   479488 20612 ffffffff 00000000 S com.sec.android.widgetapp
.programmonitorwidget
app_71    6140  225   481412 22540 ffffffff 00000000 S com.android.sec.gallery3d

app_391   6173  225   485068 26780 ffffffff 00000000 S com.farsitel.bazaar
app_14    6712  225   503704 33236 ffffffff 00000000 S com.android.vending
system    6737  225   480416 21316 ffffffff 00000000 S com.android.settings
app_42    6744  225   480480 20860 ffffffff 00000000 S com.svox.pico
app_68    6751  225   478624 21080 ffffffff 00000000 S com.google.android.partne
rsetup
app_330   6758  225   488644 22708 ffffffff 00000000 S com.yoyogames.runner
app_318   6765  225   487060 27132 ffffffff 00000000 S net.jhoobin.jhub
app_310   6776  225   480464 23548 ffffffff 00000000 S com.appslib.vending
app_240   6789  225   483284 24576 ffffffff 00000000 S cm.aptoide.pt
app_277   6800  225   481236 24140 ffffffff 00000000 S com.ada.market
app_384   6813  225   484576 24296 ffffffff 00000000 S com.dewmobile.kuaiya
app_380   6823  225   486928 27244 ffffffff 00000000 S com.estrongs.android.pop
app_67    6858  225   482568 23560 ffffffff 00000000 S com.google.android.google
quicksearchbox
root      6998  2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S kworker/u:1
app_34    7049  225   479424 21936 ffffffff 00000000 S com.sec.android.app.samsu
ngapps.una2
app_60    7102  225   500324 25060 ffffffff 00000000 S com.google.android.apps.m
aps:FriendService
app_60    7415  225   508912 28592 ffffffff 00000000 S com.google.android.apps.m
aps:GoogleLocationService
root      7450  2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S kworker/0:2
app_138   7608  225   492292 26584 ffffffff 00000000 S com.speaktoit.assistant
app_16    7635  225   484192 21172 ffffffff 00000000 S android.tts
app_48    7642  225   485668 22416 ffffffff 00000000 S com.google.android.gsf.lo
gin
app_29    7654  225   484888 30400 ffffffff 00000000 S android.process.media
root      7681  2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S kworker/0:0
app_406   7695  225   493492 29852 ffffffff 00000000 S apt.eve.dynamicanalysis
system    7712  225   480960 21292 ffffffff 00000000 S com.sec.android.app.facto
rytest
app_28    7719  225   480540 20592 ffffffff 00000000 S com.sec.phone
app_381   7738  225   490688 25820 ffffffff 00000000 S com.lenovo.anyshare.gps
app_204   7760  225   494564 29104 ffffffff 00000000 S com.rebelvox.voxer
system    7783  225   489804 23492 ffffffff 00000000 S com.android.MtpApplicatio
n
app_60    7791  225   496424 27336 ffffffff 00000000 S com.google.android.apps.m
aps:LocationFriendService
app_91    7809  225   479584 21468 ffffffff 00000000 S com.sec.android.provider.
badge
root      7816  2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S kworker/0:1
root      7818  2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S kworker/u:2
root      7819  2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S flush-0:18
root      7821  2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S kworker/u:3
root      7823  2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S kworker/u:4
root      7824  2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S kworker/u:5
root      7825  2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S kworker/u:6
root      7826  2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S kworker/u:7
root      7827  2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S kworker/u:8
root      7828  2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S kworker/u:9
root      7829  2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S kworker/u:10
root      7830  2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S kworker/u:11
root      7831  2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S kworker/u:12
root      7934  2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S migration/1
root      7935  2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S kworker/1:1
root      7936  2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S ksoftirqd/1
root      7937  2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S watchdog/1
root      7938  2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S kworker/1:0
app_116   7941  225   528836 58192 ffffffff 00000000 S com.facebook.katana
root      7953  2     0      0     ffffffff 00000000 S kworker/1:2
app_10    7962  225   556924 30200 ffffffff 00000000 S com.google.android.youtub
e
shell     8011  238   804    408   c003738c aff0bc54 S /system/bin/sh
shell     8015  8011  960    340   00000000 aff0b238 R ps
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filtering by "app_*" is definitely a step in right direction. Next, you want to filter out **system** apps: see *[How do I check if an app is a non-system app in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784505/how-do-i-check-if-an-app-is-a-non-system-app-in-android)*

Note that definition of system *vs.* non-system apps is vague: e.g. Facebook may be preinstalled or not, depending on the goodwill of the manufacturer (and provider).

Also note that some apps may run more than one process.