# Kernel Wrapper Application Installation after temporary routing of the Android Phone

Tags: android

Is it possible to install a wrapper application around the kernel (for monitoring all activities at the kernel level) after temporary routing of the android phone ?

If "yes" can I get pointers to some resources from where I can learn the same.

Answer (score 0):

[How to run terminal command in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843250/how-to-run-terminal-command-in-android-application)

Essentially you'd need to run su to grant your app root permissions and then run whatever commands you'd need as for 'monitoring all activities at the kernel level' (dmesg maybe?).

Comment: So I need to run su within my Android application. But is that possible without permanently rooting the Android Phone considering that I want to run this application at all times in the background ?

Comment: The very definition of root is that you get su level permissions.  You have to be "rooted" to be considered (s)uper (u)ser.  So no, you can't do it without rooting.  And rooting is not permanent.

Comment: As for temporal rooting in a strict sense, it does not exist. But you can always un-root a device if you want.